# Problemas com Python3 em conexão com Firebird2.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebird, firebird-2.5

Fiz esse código Python (básico de conexão com Firebird):

```py
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(
    host='192.168.1.17', database='/home/firebird/questor.fdb',
    user='sysdba', password='masterkey'
)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select nomeusuario from usuario")

print(cur.fetchall())
```

e está retornando esse erro no console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Thales/PycharmProjects/TesteBanco/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    user='sysdba', password='masterkey'
  File "C:\Users\Thales\PycharmProjects\TesteBanco\venv\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 784, in connect
    load_api(fb_library_name)
  File "C:\Users\Thales\PycharmProjects\TesteBanco\venv\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 220, in load_api
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'api', ibase.fbclient_API(fb_library_name))
  File "C:\Users\Thales\PycharmProjects\TesteBanco\venv\lib\site-packages\fdb\ibase.py", line 1385, in __init__
    raise Exception("The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.")

Exception: The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.
```

Pontos a levantar aqui:

Já tenho o Classic Server do Firebird2.5 instalado;

Já instalei o pacote 'fdb' que está no inicio do código; e

Procurei a solução a manhã toda antes de vir criar este tópico!

Comment: Olá Thales, conseguiu testar a minha resposta? Caso tenha te ajudado peço por gentileza que marque como certa. Se precisar de ajuda estou a disposição. Grato!

Comment: Na realidade como você foi o único que se propôs a ajudar, e que de fato sua resposta é uma resposta válida para o problema de não achar o package do FDB, marquei como certa. POREM, no meu caso eu estava com o Python3 32bits numa maquina de 64bits, e por consequência gera o mesmo erro como se não tivesse o pacote. Obrigado de qualquer maneira!

Comment: Olá @Thales, fico feliz que tenha conseguido resolver o problema. Abraço e até a próxima!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que está retornando:

"A localização da biblioteca cliente do Firebird não pôde ser determinada."

Tenta instalar a biblioteca novamente desta forma:

Entrar no `prompt` de comando do Windows.

Entrar na pasta onde o Python está instalado com o comando `cd`.

Depois digite este comando:

`pip install fdb`

O diretório do Python deve estar no `path` do Windows.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fdb/